# How to use Create Command in yii2?

Tags: mysqli, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i want to create a new table and then insert value into it using create command. This is the code which i tried

```
if ( $model->save() )
            {
                $first_val      =   $model->num_start - 1;
                $connection     =   \Yii::$app()->db;
                $transaction    =   $connection->beginTransaction();
                try 
                {
                    $q =  "CREATE TABLE range_{$model->id}( id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (id) ); " ;      
                    $connection->createCommand($q)->execute(); // new table created
                    $transaction->commit();
                    if ( $model->num_start > 1 )
                    {
                        $r =  "INSERT INTO range_{$model->id}( id ) VALUES ({$first_val});" ;      
                        $connection->createCommand($r)->execute(); // new value inserted
                        $transaction->commit();
                    }

                } 
                catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    // react on exception   
                    $transaction->rollback();
                } 

                return $this->redirect( [ 'index' ] );
}
```

when i try to run this code i get an error `Call to undefined method Yii::app()` How can i use the create command in Yii2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed both `yii` and `yii2`:

Use:

```
\Yii::$app->db;
```

Instead of

```
\Yii::$app()->db;
```